# How to load the react page after browser refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

whenever I enter the URL http://domain.de/beta/ to my browser, I can see the content of *Verein*. If I press F5 to refresh the page, I get an 404 Not-Found error.

I'm using the BrowserRouter from react-router-dom (v.5.2.0 >
I checked the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) too and just follow the [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match)).

```
// inside my index.js of Create-React-App
render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/beta">
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/verein/contact-imprint-privacy"
          component={ContactImprintPrivacy}
        />
        <Route path="/verein" component={Verein} />
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/verein" />
        </Route>

        <Route path="*" component={FourOhFour} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I run `yarn build` and deploy the web app from `build` folder to my hosting space.
What do I miss for the page refresh?

Update, 11.07:

I have to think about how the server side should handle the URL. So, I add an *.htaccess* file with a rewrite rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /beta
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /beta/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh your application, you get a 404 Not-Found error, because your application go to the server to find /verein page, but there is none. React router is just client side routing, but the very first request will always be to the server.

You need to setup your server to catch all incoming url (/*) and render your index.html

for more detailed answer, you can read this questions accepted answer:

[QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: Thanks for your hint about "think about the server side". I solve my problem by using a .htaccess rewrite rule.